# Can I distribute/sell the results of contracted work done for me?

Tags: copyright

I need to get a 3D model done for a game I'm working on, and I plan on using [cgtrader.com](https://www.cgtrader.com/) to "hire" someone. Later, I want to release the model for other people to use once my game is done, and I want to publish it on [cgtrader](https://www.cgtrader.com/), either for free or for a very small price. Can I do that? Or does the nature of the work not allow it, since it was done for another project, not necessarily to be distributed on its own?

Answer (score 2):

You have to negotiate the ownership of the intellectual property when you hire an artist.

Most artist will sell the rights, which is what you need, but it does generally cost more. By default, artists own everything they create unless there's a contract stipulating otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an attorney to write up a contract for you which covers your intended use, stipulating copyright and licensing agreements in advance. And then, you have to find an artist prepared to sign your contract.

It might be considered expensive, but not compared to being on the wrong end of a copyright lawsuit.